# Question on Scala Abstract Type

Tags: scala

I've got a simple question for you :)
 I have the following Scala code, which compiles and gives an error.
 Actually I am expecting the code not be compiled as it has an abstract type CT. And the error is even more confusing as the scala says it can't find the type CT.

```
class Currency {   type ct=Currency } 
val c = new Currency
println(c.ct)
```

> error: value ct is not a member of Currency

I appreciate your comments,

Thanks,
-A

PS - Using sala 2.7.7

Comment: Interestingly, If I try 
          class Currency {   type ct } ; val c = new Currency ; 
The code compiles, why is that ? I guess I shouldn't be able to create a concrete instance of Currency as long as it has an abstract value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a close look at the error message: "value ct is not a member of Currency". The "value" here is significant. Currency has a type member ct, but not a value member ct. So c.ct is a type, not an expression.

Comment: Downvoted as unhelpful.  Too many uses of the word "member".  Also, add some extraneous example code to prove your formatting capability.

Answer (score 3):

In this case type ct is NOT an abstract type but a simple type alias for Currency type. Hence that expression SHOULD compile.

Regarding the println expression, you are using c.ct as a value to be printed (by calling its toString). This is NOT correct because c.ct is not a value but a type (path dependent type). Hence a valid (but somewhat meaningless) expression involving c.ct could be:

```
val a: c.ct = new Currency
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I added a comment with regard of this question.

Comment: Regarding the comment: Well, even I had come across that and thought it was a bug. But it seems that there are some reasons why it exists:
http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1753